# Bilinear interpolation in Matlab (without built in functions)

Tags: matlab, math, interpolation

I'm having some trouble understanding how to code the bilinear interpolation in Matlab. Our assignment has us using this function;

B(x,y) = z_(ij) + a*(x - xj) + b*(y - yi) + c*(x - xj)(y - yi)

We're building 2 functions, one that calculates the coefficients (Which i've done already and it passed the 'check' algorithm from the professor) and another function that computes the function. below is the code I have.
We're given, x,y,z,xi, and yi, while a,b,c have already been computed.

**My issue:** The function runs but returns a matrix when it should only return a vector. However, it does return the correct values in column 1, rows 1 & 2 which is really confusing me. Also, the values we're given are a square matrix (z) and 1x2 x and y values, however, in the second part of the problem we're givene an z = m x n matrix that is not a square matrix so my code isn't working for that. Below is my current code. Any help would be appreciated but i don't expect you to just give me the answer!

```
%Given x = [0,1], y=[0,1], z=[0,1;2,4], a = 1, b = 2, c = 1, xi = [0,.5],      yi = [0,.5]

function zi = bilinear_eval(x, y, z, a, b, c, xi, yi )
    [m,n] = size(z);
    for j = 1:length(xi)
        for i = length(x)
        zi(i,j) = z(j,j) + a*(xi(i) - x(j)) + b*(yi(i) - y(j)) + c*(xi(i) - x(j))*(yi(i) - y(j))
        end
    end
    end
```

Comment: why are the `python` or `c++` tags here?

Comment: If you want a vector output then you shouldn't be indexing `zi` with both `i` and `j`.

Comment: @taylorswift I know python and c++ so I assume if someone is able to answer it in either of those formats, I can extrapolate to Matlab as well. But I removed them for you.

Comment: I definitely realize that @excaza, however, if I simply use i OR j, it's just overwriting whatever was there before and is giving me the incorrect values. I used this indexing temporarily to 'see' what the function was giving back at all iterations

Comment: @ovp is this a question about algorithms or coding then?

Comment: @taylor swift I sincerely don't know how to answer that. Both? I'm trying to code and algorithm. Although I suppose it's more on the algorithm side since i'm certain that where my real problem is. I'm certain that it's something i'm not understanding about the interpolation formula.

Comment: Is `for i = length(x)` should be `for i = 1:length(x)`? otherwise, omit the `for` (and his `end`), and you can replace `i` by `length(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what order of interpolation you're using, but knowing Lagrange polynomials or shape functions from finite element analysis can be helpful here.

If I had a function f(x, y) where I wanted to interpolate between four values I'd write it like this:

```
f(x, y) = f1*N1(r, s) + f2*N2(r, s) + f3*N3(r, s) + f4*N4(r, s)
```

where

```
-1 <= r <= 1
-1 <= s <= 1
```

and

```
N1(r, s) = (1-r)*(1-s)/4.0
N2(r, s) = (1+r)*(1-s)/4.0
N3(r, s) = (1+r)*(1+s)/4.0
N4(r, s) = (1-r)*(1+s)/4.0
```

This arrangement assumes that the four points are arranged in such a way that f1 is at the lower left, f2 at lower right, f3 at upper right, and f4 at upper left in a quadrilateral.

The interpolation functions range in value from zero to one.